# Decompile Adobe Air application to get a swf from it?

Tags: flash, air

It is possible to decompile an Adobe Air application to extract a SWF from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a free solution but does the job http://www.swfvampire.com/swfwindowvampire.php

Comment: In the end I got my Adobe Air application supplied as a SWF :)

Comment: And I was about to say that! Sometimes you miss the most obvious solution. Give your self a pat on the back. Good job, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

It is a zip archive.

On linux

```
unzip file.air
```